# Can't get rid of a notification

Tags: gnome, notification, rhythmbox

So I opened Rhythmbox with an mp3 file by mistake. Since then I got a notification and I can't get rid of it. I restarted Gnome, restarted my computer, disabled notifications for Rhythmbox from within the program and from the Settings dialog, but the notification always comes back (it disappears after reboot but then reappears).

[image]

GNOME Shell 3.34.1

Is there any way to fix this without complete re-installation of Ubuntu? I could not find an answer specific to this problem anywhere.

Comment: Use Clementine ;-) You should consider making a bug report.

Comment: It's a Gnome notifications issue that has nothing to do with Rhythmbox (unfortunately, because removing it also doesn't solve it).

Answer (score 1):

This is how I finally solved it:

Remove the notification-daemon:

sudo apt-get purge notification-daemon

Then reinstall:

sudo apt install notification-daemon

EDIT: After another reboot the notification came back :( I guess it's format and reinstall Ubuntu.